# SUM("Box Office Revenue ($)")/count("Box Office Revenue ($)")) the formula phrase is not correct

Tags: formula, spreadsheet

An error occurs in the formula while doing a calculation field in pivot table on spreadsheet.

The equation is used to calculate the sum of two tables the equations goes like** `=SUM("Box Office Revenue ($)")/count("Box Office Revenue ($)"))** the formula` phrase error

Comment: So have you done the calculation on the cells manually? Do you get a valid correct result? If not are any values in cells corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner here, but this has worked for me in Google Sheets.

Correct formula:

```
=SUM('Box Office Revenue ($)')/COUNT('Box Office Revenue ($)')
```

[image: screenshot]